# Java mission control configure events from command line

Tags: events, command, line, jmc

I want to configure JMC such that it will send email notifications when CPU hike beyond a threhold. I want to do it from command line because JMC will be run from the Jenkins job.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, no server side rules engine just yet. :)